# React JS Adding a conditional loops in react map function

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, api, jsx

I have a react application which fetches products from a json file, with 2 buttons on top each button will show another json/menuitems, so as some of the jsons im working with have empty categories, the app crashes, what i want to do is a conditional loop which will either skip the category or show it as empty, as long as it doesnt crash.

you can see in the application when you click on menu 2 it crashes.

here is the live snippet: https://codesandbox.io/embed/j29k59x4ly?fontsize=14

and here is the mapping function itself from ItemList.js line 139 > 149

```
 {activelist.children[this.state.selected].children.map(
                (item, index) => (
                  <Item
                    className="person"
                    key={index}
                    Title={item.name}
                    onClick={this.handleClick}
                    index={index}
                  />
                )
              )}
```

Comment: Hi, it is a little confuse, can you explain what 'this.state.selected' do? i notice you have MENUS, CATEGORIES and ITENS, when you select one of these you save the value in this.state.selected?

Comment: the categories are maped in another component "categories" so that it shows in the scrolling menu bar, with a function that returns a number index whenever a category is clicked, which will map the category items according to the index, selected state begins with 0 as the first category and keeps changing on click to show the items within it.

Answer (score 0):

I found the bug at line `123` and `124`

```
const selectedChild = activelist.children[this.state.selected];
const selectedItem = selectedChild.children[this.state.itemSelected];
```

the data of `selectedChild` is a collection of categories, but the first item has no `children` attribute then make `selectcedChild.children` get `undefined` and cause issue.

```js
[
  {
    name: "Empty Category"
    type: "category", //<-- No `children` attribute
  }, {
    children:  [{…}, {…}, {…}]
    name: "Burgers"
    type: "category"
  }, {
    children: (2) [{…}, {…}]
    name: "Sets"
    type: "category"
  }
]
```

My solution is:

1. You can format all item of `selectedChild` has `children` attribute. `children: []` in no data case.
2. Or `return` a message when it has no children. To prevent get the item of `undefined`

```js
const selectedChild = activelist.children[this.state.selected]; 
if (!selectedChild.children) return <span>Out of stock...</span> // handle issue here
const selectedItem = selectedChild.children[this.state.itemSelected];
```

Comment: thank you for your input, but im not sure how can solution 1 be applied, and as for solution 2 i tried it before and after the return it showed the same error, i hope you dont mind if you can demonstrate your answer to me.

Comment: line `165` and `length` to check condition `selectedItem.children.length`. Here is what I fixed so far https://codesandbox.io/embed/j29k59x4ly?fontsize=14

Comment: The link you sent is the same link I posted, can you fork or save the changes you made?

Answer (score 0):

After I debugged. I found that your 2 APIs return different format. The response of API for `this.state.items`, all have `children` attribute. The second one for `this.state.items2` has the first item without `children` attribute.

You can format the data response of `items2` before `setState` for it, in `Active2` function.
And this will solve the problem.

```js
  Active2() {
  /* This is the way you clone a nested object. You can read here:
  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#Deep_Clone */
    let newActivelist = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state.items2)) 
    // Filter item has children only (remvoe "Empty Category")
    let newChildren = this.state.items2.children.filter(item => item.children)
    // Mutation new activelist
    newActivelist.children = newChildren
    this.setState({ activelist: newActivelist}); //CHANGED
  }
```

Another option to clone a nested object is use [_.cloneDeep()](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#cloneDeep) of [lodash](https://lodash.com/) library

```
import _ from 'lodash'
let newActivelist = _.cloneDeep(this.state.items2)
```